# Does $(\mathbf{A}^{-1})^{H} = (\mathbf{A}^{H})^{-1}$ holds for complex-valued matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Does $(\mathbf{A}^{-1})^{H} = (\mathbf{A}^{H})^{-1}$ holds for complex-valued matrix?

Based on my quick proof it seems like this will hold but I am not sure if there is anything about complex-valued matrices that I am missing here. I am personally not too familiar with complex-valued matrices.
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{A}^{-1})^{H}\mathbf{A}^H = (\mathbf{AA}^{-1})^H = I^H = I\\
\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{A}^{-1})^{H} = (\mathbf{A^{-1}}\mathbf{A})^H = I^H = I\\
\end{align}

Comment: The proof is ok: $A^HB^H=(BA)^H$ holds just like $A^tB^t=(BA)^t$ does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it holds for complex matrices. And your proof is correct, although too long. If you have two square matrices of the same size $A$ and $B$, then, in order to prove that $B=A^{-1}$, it is enough to prove that **one** of these assertions hold:

- $AB=\operatorname{Id}$;
- $BA=\operatorname{Id}$.

In fact, if one of them holds, then the other one will hold too.